# Web fonts using arabic characters 

Tags: fonts, font-face

I want to use arabic character on my website I used @fontface to do so but the problem that the characters in firefox is deattached but in chrome is working fine 
I used the arabic encoding range trying to solve this.

Arabic encoding range:

> U+0600-U+06FF,U+0750-U+077F,U+08A0-U+08FF,U+FB50-U+FDFF,U+FE70-U+FEFF,U+1EE00-U+1EEFF

In firefox:
ب س م

In chrome:
بسم

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

User the correct character set and if possible use Arabic transparent as font.

```
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />
```

I am using Arabic transparent for my website and it is coming up nice